# JAX-RS Client vs MicroProfile Rest Client

Tags: jax-rs, cxf

Where is the difference between a JAX-RS Client implementation like Apache CXF and the MicroProfile Rest Client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The different clients implement different standards. The JAX-RS Client is implemented according to JSR 370 https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=370 while the other one implements the MicroProfile specification http://microprofile.io/project/eclipse/microprofile-rest-client.